# C# Get Console to (SPEAK) a response

Tags: c#

I want it when I type in How are you today? I want the console to Speak
`Console.WriteLine("Response");`!

```
case "How are you today":
    Console.WriteLine("I am good how are you?");
    break;
```

Comment: First off, generally the tag in the title is not really necessary. Secondly, how is this different from your other question? I see no difference between the two. If there is a difference in your situation, you'll need to specify that.

Comment: @Ben I am sorry if I am Unclear! It's different because I read the article in the last "Answer" It was not working because I had missing Strings I could not find on the Article!

Comment: The article in the last answer gives a complete example.

Comment: @jdphenix There is also no need to down vote every question I ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
...

 // Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer.
      SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

      // Configure the audio output. 
      synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();


      synth.Speak("I am good how are you?");
```